# Negative electrostatic potential energy interpretation

Tags: electrostatics

While going through an introductory text in electricity and magnetism , in a section dealing with the electrostatic potential energy (EPE) , the author gave an example of the EPE in an ionic crystal , after some computations the EPE of this configuration (the ionic crystal lattice) turns out :

$U=\textbf{-}\frac{0.8738*N*e^2}{a}$

where $U$ is the EPE of the crystal , $N$ is the number of ions (positive and negative) contained within the lattice , $a$ was the spacing between the ions (see picture) and $e$ the elementary charge .

Then the author sad that the negative sign meant that "work would have to be done to take the crystal apart into ".
 .

How did he come to this conclusion ? and what does it even mean for a given configuration to have a $\textbf{negative}$ potential energy ?

Reference :Electricity and Magnetism (E.M.Purcell)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPE is the energy required to gather all ions from infinity to create the crystal. If this energy is negative, than the opposite: "taking the crystal apart and sending all  ions to infinity" requires positive energy.

Comment: How could you use $\textbf{negative}$ energy to assemble anything ? or put in another way what does a $\textbf{negative}$ energy mean conceptually ?

Comment: First, suppose you have just one positive ion and on negative ion at a distance from each other. They will move towards each other and you do not need to invest energy for that to happen. On the contrary, the ions can ***release*** energy. Second, the negative sign of EPE is an outcome of the fact that initially, at infinity, it is convenient to set potential energy as zero.

Comment: So if I've understood well , the minus sign just refers to the fact that it's the energy released by letting these ions travel from infinity and lump together to form this lattice .and the amount of energy required to bring them back to infinity is just the same but with a plus sign , isn'it?

Comment: That is very right.

Answer (score 1):

> Then the author sad that the negative sign meant that "work would have to be done to take the crystal apart into ".
>   How did he come to this conclusion?

Let us think about the crystal given in the question.

It appears there are 14  negative ions and thirteen positive ones and have been assembled by doing work to bring them together in the arrangement shown.

EPE of this configuration (the ionic crystal lattice) comes out to be negative.

And it must be true/correct.

As the ionic crystal is existing in a bound state. All bound systems have negative energy otherwise it will fall apart.

The one extra negative ion must be bound by the field of thirteen pairs of ions.

Therefore one needs to do external work to take the configuration apart.

The most talked about bound system H-atom has also the same feature of negative potential energy as well as the total energy of (-) sign.

Therefore the question raised is not tenable.

Answer (score 1):

Despite you've already chosen a best answer, let me make sure you've got the point: **energy is meaningless**, what you actually care about are **energy differences**.

Energy is free. even the electricity company agrees. How much energy do you want to have? A million joules? It's okay, now you have.

Why? Because the **zero point is arbitrary**. You can choose where to put the energy reference.

The thing is that what we actually do is setting $E=0$ at infinity. 
That means that you would be able to reach infinity (in absence of obstacles) if you had 0 or positive energy. Hence, your energy is less than 0 if you are bounded to Earth. But having negative energy doesn't mean anything special. It just means "less than infinity".

However, you could also have stablished the crystal to have 0 energy. If so, the infinity would have a positive energy.

The fact is that there is a difference between infinity and you. Why is that? Because it costs work to overcome cohesive forces. So you have to add work to escape the net. Therefore, the outside has more energy.

But where you set $0J$ is arbitrary.

We jsut care about energy differences, which are work. Work is measurable, meaningful, and expensive. Energy is not.